# Sketch - Apply transformation to shape?

Tags: svg, sketch-app, transform

How can I apply a transformation to a shape in Sketch, so that on export it actually changes the SVG coordinate values instead of just applying the transformation with a transform-property?

I made an arrow like such, you can see the rotation value in the image. I want to get rid of the rotation value (90 deg) and still keep the arrow pointing downwards.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any trick to do it inside Sketch (without any plugin). If someone has a better reply, I'll delete mine.

What you can try is to use [SVGO](https://github.com/svg/svgo).

Here's the [Sketch plugin](https://github.com/sketch-hq/svgo-compressor).

Here's a [Web GUI](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) if you want to try it without installing the package.

I tried with an arrow downloaded from flaticon, and it removed the 90° rotation I applied.
Those two parameters seem interesting : `convertPathData` and `convertTransform`.

Comment: Don't delete your answer please, even if someone comes up with a better one. It's good to have different answers, even when they might not be what the OP expects.

Comment: Alright, I'll keep it then :)

Answer (score 0):

@Johan Dahl

Select the arrow shape and then go to Layer > Combine > Flatten.